# How to set /usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-g++ to gww?

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, c++, mingw32

I use cross compiling for C++ using MinGW... I use

> /usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-g++ *filename*.cpp

to compile, but I want to be able to type

> gww *filename*.cpp

I think I need to set a PATH variable or something?

## Note

Please note I am quite inexperienced with Linux, but can get around easily with the terminal and stuff. If this is very basic, tell me how to do it.. Note that this is a very hard search engine hit (set /usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-g++?), sick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change your `$PATH` since `/usr/bin` is already in your path. You could actually run the command as

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ filename.cpp
```

That's not very pretty though, so instead, do one of

#### 1. Make an alias for the command.

Open `~/.bashrc` and add this line:

```
alias gww='/usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-g++'
```

Now, open a new terminal so that `.bashrc` is re-read (or source it manually with `source ~/.bashrc`) and you will be able to use `gww` as the command's name.

#### 2. Make a link to it in `/usr/bin`.

You can create a symlink to the compiler and name the symlink `gww`:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s i586-mingw32msvc-g++ gww
```

Both approaches will let you invoke `i586-mingw32msvc-g++` by running `gww`. You can use the one you prefer. The main difference is that the 1st approach will make it available to your user only, while the second will be system-wide.